# how do i add items to a queue then start sending them one after one?

Tags: c#, queue, client-server, send

[image]

I'm making a file transfer application between (client-server) and have the tools I need but I'm a little confused about how to send the files. This is what I have:

- **localListView** - a tool that i can get the selectedItems which has fileName, path, current address, etc
- **remoteListView** - the same of the above
- Send method that takes Source path (filePath from the localListView) and DestinationPath (currAddress from remoteListView)
- The tools at the bottom of the picture is XPTable tool

They all works fine, but I just need a way to write a code to put the items I want to send in a queue.  I also need a pointer that points to the current file which my application is sending. After the first file is sent successfully the pointer should go to the next file in the list and start the send method.

How do i do that?

Please if you have a good idea of how could this done either in c# or pseudo code or anything that would help me I would be thankful.

Comment: Where exactly do you need help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it this way .. when you add the items to your list .. set each item tag to false .. that means you didn't send it yet

```
item.Tag = false;
```

then when you start sending the items .. it will check each item's tag if false(not sent yet) you will send it and set its tag to True (item sent) and so on

```
void startTransferFiles()
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
    {
        if ((bool)item.Tag == false)
        {
            Send(item.ToolTipText);
            item.Tag = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I'm not completely sure where you need help, I'll give you an overview of good techniques:

I would imagine you would have to implement a reply.
I expect you are using TCP already, which comes with automatic verification of correctly received packets. But with this built in functionality, you cannot verify whole files have been sent successfully.

If you are ok increasing the amount of packets being sent between your server and client, you could write a reply that is sent by the server when the whole file is received. Upon getting this reply, the pointer could be increased by one (go to the next list item), the send method would be run with the next file and the whole process would be repeated.

Having send/reply or push/listen functionality from both your client and server is a good way to push back errors or confirmations from one to the other, and keeps both ends working - knowing what the other is doing.

If you are trying to minimalise packets being sent between client and server you could use UDP, but this really isn't a good option for things like file transfer. You can also simply stream all of your data in a big chunk rather than bit by bit - but you'll get no real verification of each file being sent, as you want.

Comment: im using TCP to send/recieve files.. i can get a reply message from server when the file successfully sent.. the send method works fine .. im wondering about the Technic of putting the items in a queue so when the reply comes from server "SENT" .. i go to the next file .. i would write the code of that.. but i would like to use a the queue library in .Net or some other libraries that would be ensured that its going the right way .. my question is kinda like when you go shopping and you are not sure what shirt you want to buy. lol

Comment: Maybe this page will help you understand what you are trying to do in some more detail: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379571(v=vs.80).aspx